# How to make an output file of n*n matrix,by taking n from the user, with the numbers generated in pairs?

Tags: c++, vector, random, 2d-vector

Currently I have a pre-made 6X6 matrix in a text file like this:

```
2 6 3 1 0 4
4 2 7 7 2 8
4 7 3 2 5 1
7 6 5 1 1 0
8 4 6 0 0 6
1 3 1 8 3 8
```

and I made a code that is reading from a file i have made. However I want to have user make a grid for themselves (i.e. 3X3 or 10X10). Which then writes to a text file automatically like in similar fashion and then have that read-in instead. It is a basic memory match card game, so I need to have rand() which generates equal pair so the game can be over when every pair in the grid has been found. Thank you so much for your time!

```
/*Here are the snippets of my code*/

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;  

//global 2d vectors that are associated with the game
vector<vector<int> > game_grid; 
vector<vector<int> > hidden_grid;
vector <vector<int> > guessed;

void initialize_grid() {
ifstream input_file;
input_file.open("grid.txt");
int num;

if (input_file) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        vector<int> row; // game grid
        vector<int> row2; // hidden grid
        vector<int> row3; // guessed grid
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            if (input_file >> num)
                row.push_back(num);
            row2.push_back(-1);
            row3.push_back(0);
        }
        game_grid.push_back(row);
        hidden_grid.push_back(row2);
        guessed.push_back(row3);
    }
    cout << "Get is ready, Challenger!" << endl << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Womp. File open failed!";
}
return;
}

void print_grid() {
cout << "Game  grid" << endl;
cout << " -------------------------" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    cout << " | ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        cout << game_grid[i][j] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl << " -------------------------" << endl;
}
cout << endl;
}

void print_hidden_grid(int r1 = -1, int r2 = -1, int c1 = -1, int c2 = -1) {
cout << "Attempt:" << endl;
if (r1 != -1) {
    hidden_grid[r1][c1] = game_grid[r1][c1];
}
if (r2 != -1) {
    hidden_grid[r2][c2] = game_grid[r2][c2];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    cout << " | ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        if (hidden_grid[i][j] > -1)
            cout << hidden_grid[i][j] << " | ";
        else
            cout << "  | ";
    }
    cout << endl << " -------------------------" << endl;
}
cout << endl;

if (r1 != -1) {
    if (game_grid[r1][c1] == game_grid[r2][c2]) {
        guessed[r1][c1] = 1;
        guessed[r2][c2] = 1;
        cout << "You have a match!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        hidden_grid[r1][c1] = -1;
        hidden_grid[r2][c2] = -1;
    }
}
cout << endl << endl;
}

void print_current_grid() {
cout << "Current Grid:" << endl;
cout << " -------------------------" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    cout << " | ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        if (hidden_grid[i][j] > -1)
            cout << hidden_grid[i][j] << " | ";
        else
            cout << "  | ";
    }
    cout << endl << " -------------------------" << endl;
}
cout << endl << endl;
}


 .......
```

Comment: I put a proposal to detect matrix size in an answer .. if this is what you wanted. After I do not understand what you want about the _rand_

Comment: Sorry, I was working on it. Still no luck. Added a comment. The book has "Allow the user to specify the size of the grid instead of maintaining a 6x6 grid. Then, generate a grid based on the user’s input." I am very lost and no resources beside Stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand you want to auto detect the size of the matrix when you read it ? If yes you can do something like that in `initialize_grid` :

```
void initialize_grid() {
  ifstream input_file;
  input_file.open("grid.txt");
  int num;

  if (input_file) {
    // detect size
    int size = 0;
    string line;

    if (!getline(input_file, line))
      return;

    istringstream iss(line);

    while (iss >> num)
      size += 1;

    input_file.clear();
    input_file.seekg(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      vector<int> row; // game grid
      vector<int> row2; // hidden grid
      vector<int> row3; // guessed grid
      for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        if (input_file >> num)
          row.push_back(num);
        row2.push_back(-1);
        row3.push_back(0);
      }
      game_grid.push_back(row);
      hidden_grid.push_back(row2);
      guessed.push_back(row3);
    }
    cout << "Get is ready, Challenger!" << endl << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Womp. File open failed!";
  }
}
```

and  else where you replace `6` by `game_grid.size()` (using `size_t` rather than *int* to type the indexes)

Comment: thank you so much. I am new to c++. The book wants me to do "Allow the user to specify the size of the grid instead of maintaining a 6x6 grid. Then, generate a grid based on the user’s input. " But my problem is if they choose 3X3 and since I made a text file, the game will never be over because the pairs are missing. So that's where I am having issues.

Comment: what rule to follow to "generate a grid based on the user’s input" ? just use random values ?

Comment: That was my initial thought too. But i don;t know how to make random function that will generate pairs. Meaning I can have 3 1's and since rand never produce another 1, the game will never be over.

Comment: @Ulta I still do not understand where there are 'pairs', really you are unclear. **We do not have your book, nor magic crystal balls**

Comment: Sorry friend. You know like the one in my text file. I have typed 4 1's, 4 2's etc. For 6X6 matrix they all have match therefore user can finish a game. And if i use random function, I may not get matches since I have no control over that therefore game may never end. My problem is that I can't make a grid given by user and then generate equal numbers of matches to finish a game. I have no clue.

Comment: @Ulta after reading he matrix by `initialize_grid()` the program has to detect how much times each number is present inside (in your example it is 4) ? then to generate an other matrix of the same size and the same and random number repeated in the same way ?

Comment: Appreciate your help. I will do that (don't know how yet, but will look on this). Thank you so much friend.